# C# hide form controls using base form class

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, form-control

I have some forms that have menu control on them. This menu control should be visible or invisible based on the user that logged in to the system. I can hide this control using this code block:

```
    public myForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myMenu.Visible = CheckUserRole();
    }
```

It works perfectly. But I have several forms that have the same code structure and menu control. How can I create a base form and inheritance this structure to every form I have?

I have created a base form named `BaseForm` with a menu control then I call it in my forms like this:

```
public partial class myFrom : BaseForm
{
    public myForm() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }...
```

but I don't know what to do with my base class?

**Can you tell me how can I apply this structure in my project?**

Thank you.

Comment: Why isnt `myMenu.Visible = CheckUserRole();` in your base class? That would seem to work as you've described it.

Comment: @Jamiec I did! But it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Why did it not solve your problem, what happened? What did you expect to happen? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought this would solve it:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 2 == 0;
    }
}

public partial class MyForm : WindowsFormsApp7.BaseForm
{
    public MyForm() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Visible = !button1.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `MyForm` components? How can I load them? This code loads `BaseForm`s components.

Comment: @Badiparmagi - Yes, you're right. I forgot it was a `private void`.

Comment: @Badiparmagi - When you start inheriting forms you begin to lose designer support so it's often a good idea to get used to editing the forms manually.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing before asking the question but no luck. I guess I will check the role in every form after initializing the components. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Badiparmagi - I just tested my code with `button1.Visible = DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 2 == 0;` in my `BaseForm`'s constructor and it worked like a treat. You must be doing something different.

Comment: When base class' menu control is visible then I have 2 menu controls on my form after login. how can I hide my child control if it is hidden on the base form? Because each form menu controls have different menu items. :/

Comment: @Badiparmagi - I've updated my answer to show how to solve your issue. It worked fine for me.